# Complex numbers, de Moivre's theorem

Tags: complex-numbers

I don't know how I should solve this question:

If $0<\theta<\pi/2$ and $z=(\sin\theta+i(1-\cos\theta))^2$ 
find in its simplest form $\arg z$

I know that using de Moivre's theorem I should multipy angle by two but there is $i(1-\cosθ)$ and I don't know if I should multipy only $\cos\theta$ which would give $i-i\cos2\theta$ ?

Comment: Just because something is called $\theta$, it does not mean that it is the angle you are looking for. De Moivre's formula says that there is exactly a real number $\alpha\in[0,2\pi)$ such that $\frac{z}{\sqrt{ z\overline z}}=\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha$. For such real number $\alpha$, it is true that $z^2=(z\overline z)\left(\cos(2\alpha)+i\sin(2\alpha)\right)$. Doing the aforementioned calcs, it might turn out that $\alpha$ has a non-trivial dependence on $\theta$.

Answer (score 3):

We have

\begin{align}
z&=\left[2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}+i\left(2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right]^2\\
&=4\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}\left(\cos\frac{\theta}{2}+i\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\right)^2\\
&=4\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}\left(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta\right)\\
\end{align}

$\arg z=\theta$.

Comment: I don't understand how did we get the second line. Could you explain me that, please?

Comment: $2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$ is a common factor. So we have $\displaystyle 2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}+i\left(2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}\right)
=2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\left(\cos\frac{\theta}{2}+i\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$

Comment: Oh, and you squared it at once. Now I can see it. Thank you very much!